# How do I change that string in Regex

Tags: regex

I want to use data within a csv-file that is sort of like that:

```
Weisse Strasse 1004317 Timothenau
Merzenstrasse 13 90114317 Meerseburg
```

into

```
Weisse Strasse 10 04317 Timothenau
Merzenstrasse 13 901 14317 Meerseburg
```

which means I need to check 1 word that consists of at least 6 chars/digits up to 9 chars/digits and retransform it into 2 words where the second word must have 5 digits and the first word will have all the other ones.

I tried to build a regex-find-comand with that

```
(\d{7,})
```

but even that is not outputting anything I need correctly and failed fully with building the replace-command.

Could someone please help me?

Comment: Try something like `(?<!\d)(\d{3})(\d{4,})(?!\d)` and replace with `$1 $2`. See https://regex101.com/r/foQg78/1

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
(?<!\d)(\d{1,4})(\d{5})(?!\d)
```

and replace wit `$1 $2`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/foQg78/3)

The `(?<!\d)...(?!\d)` lookarounds make sure the numbers matched are only 6 to 9 digit numbers.

**Pattern details**

- `(?<!\d)` - no digit allowed immediately to the left of the current location
- `(\d{1,4})` - Group 1 (`$1`): one to four digits
- `(\d{5})` - Group 2 (`$2`): five digits
- `(?!\d)` - no digit allowed immediately to the right of the current location (so, the Group 2 five digits are the last in a number).